# sort a List using 2 threads

Tags: java, multithreading, sorting, arraylist

I'm working on a project and I didn't get this part:

> use two threads to sort an ArrayList. each thread will have a sort of
>   half the list. the main thread will wait the two threads to finish,
>   then he will take care of merging the two lists from the sort of two
>   other threads. at the end we will have a sorted list. to merge the two
>   lists should not be the sort of conventional manner.

I try like this in `class ListePersonne` and this class sort an `ArrayList`:

```
 Thread T1 = new ListePersonne( mylist.subList(0, unique.size()/2));
 Thread T2 = new ListePersonne(mylist.subList(unique.size()/2, unique.size())  );
 T1.start();
 T2.start();
```

but in the result I got just the 1st part done but not the 2nd

Comment: Did you wait for the threads to finish?

Comment: If it's merging you don't understand, see this merge sort algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort

Comment: You didn't give enough code/information to diagnose. You must `join` on both threads before merging the list parts, that's one thing.

Comment: @user1417996 please provide the whole source code, how do you whait for result, merge lists etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Check that before merging sorting of both sublists is completed

2) Check that you use synchronized access to array list from multiple threads.

Comment: no i'm not using synchronized access there is just 10 element in my list !!

Comment: No, there is no shared data between two workers so no syncronization is needed. But @user1417996, you have a **very misguided** reason for not synchronizing! What does it matter how many elements there are in the list?

Comment: It could be a problem even if you have single shared variable and access it from multiple threads: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Memory_Model

Answer (score 0):

arraylist is not threadsafe

try vector instead ?

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Vector.html

Comment: The arraylists are used from a single thread at a time anyway so threadsafety is not the issue.

Comment: FYI Vectors aren't threadsafe, either. They're just *synchronized*, which in practice hurts more than it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is homework i won't give you code. Here are hints

1. Use `Future<List>` along with `Callable<List>` and `executor`. `Callable<T>`
   allows you to return a type unlike the Runnable, which cannot.
2. `future.get()` will block until the thread completes execution. Do
   this for both the threads.
3. Once you have the two sorted lists, merge.

Dunno if your teacher will accept this solution though in case he hasn't taught your about the Executor framework, though I'm sure you'll be able to convince him/her ;)